# How to make Buttons work on mobile in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

I am working on a 2D Platformer for mobile in unity. On the main menu screen I have two buttons. One is play and the other is quit. I am just wondering how would I make the buttons take a touch input once it is on the phone. I did switch the build to Andorid. is that all that is needed or is there something else? I am doing the project in c#.

Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is all that is needed. It will take touch input on phones.